# Using XMLHttprequest in web workers

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

I get the following error when I try to use XHR call in web workers.

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load file. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP "
cant we make external URL request using Web Workers ?

Comment: yeah you can, just not to any URLs that you can't use normal ajax for. you can't use JSONp, so $.ajax might be a little more restricted than normal...

Comment: Is the same working outside a web worker?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3076414/1048572